# Python how to print all object properties in one line

Tags: python

How to print all object properties in one like something like:

```
print obj
```

but this does not print all properties of the object

Comment: Have you tried looping through the object and printing it that way?

Comment: ... `vars(obj)`

Comment: If obj is an instance of a Class, you could try:  `print( dir(obj) )`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use builtin method `dir(obj)`

The default `dir()` mechanism behaves differently with different types of objects, as it attempts to produce the most relevant, rather than complete, information:

If the object is a module object, the list contains the names of the module’s attributes.
If the object is a type or class object, the list contains the names of its attributes, and recursively of the attributes of its bases.
Otherwise, the list contains the object’s attributes’ names, the names of its class’s attributes, and recursively of the attributes of its class’s base classes.

source : https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir

Answer (score 2):

You can add build-in function to your object (e.g `__str__(`) or `__repr__()` )

```
class MyObject:

    def __init__(self):
        #add proprieties
        self.x = 32
        self.y = 43

    def __str__(self):
        return ("Object: " + str(self.x) + " " + str(self.y))
```